# Earning Transfer to new Admob

Tags: admob

About 2 weeks ago I am shifted to new AdMob.In previous AdMob I was having some balance but It is not showing in the new AdMob. Every thing just started from Zero. Can anybody tell that how can I retrieve my balance?

Answer (score 0):

Your balance will not be transferred. It will be paid out to you.

Comment: It'll be paid automatically or Should I write up them email?